# Understanding a 404 error in IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, http-status-code-404

I have a classic asp web application in which I've created a custom friendly 404 page.   Also within that page, I have logic to email me the 404 info so I can check it out as to why it happened.

One of the pieces of info I email to myself is

Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

As I understand it, it should tell me the origin of the 404, ie. the page which is making the request to the file that doesn't exist.

However, I get notifications where the Referer is referencing a page in my site that doesn't exist in the first place.  How can this be?  Am I pulling the wrong ServerVariable?  Is someone trying to do some cross site scripting?

Comment: The http_referer has certain issues: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer The notifications you are getting is that the result of you own test or the result of a visitor?

Comment: The result of a visitor.  Is there a better server variable I could pull from?

Comment: Take your pick:  <%
for each x in Request.ServerVariables
  response.write(x & "<br>")
next
%>

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of all of the server variables available, but is there a specific one that can prevent the issue I'm having?

Comment: As far as I know no. It is not always possible to retrieve the 'true' referer. Like the wiki explains some proxies removes the headers and settings inside the browser affects the value.

Comment: Turn up the logging of IIS to investigate why you are receiving non-existing referer's.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server.  It's a shared hosting environment.